# Not Selectors in Model, Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with name `Category`.
I got `user_id` and `category_id` my `UserCategory` model.
I want to select all Categories which does not have a particular `user_id`.

How to do this.?

I need to make a dropdown list which do not show the Categories that the user selected before, which gets saved in `UserCategory` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, ActiveRecord has built-in support for [NOT conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions):

```
Category.where.not(user_id: id)
```

For a many-to-many situation, given `Category` and `User`:

```
Category.where.not(id: current_user.categories.pluck(:id))
```

This will grab all categories, excluding the current user's categories by ID.

Comment: Category Field do not have user_id.
user_id is in UserCategory Model